# web2py button with action and visual pudates

Tags: ajax, button, web2py

I have a view with a button and a DIV

I am trying to have this kind of functionality:

1. if the button is clicked - a controller method is executed ( i have the method, db.insert, etc.) 
                             - if test (inside the controller method) is passed the button dissapears and the div appears ( I thought at using ajax - not to refresh the hole page)
2. whenever the page is refreshed the test has to be made again for the button to be visible or not

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
{{=DIV(A('click me',callback=URL('mycallback'),target="me"),_id="me")}}

def mycallback():
    # do whatever you need to do
    return DIV("I will appear in place of he link when you click")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good aproach, it works for me ( even though I can't make it work - is there a typo maybe? ) but for my future use, can I separate the 'button' from the div: can I get two actions one that makes the button invisible and another that makes the div appear?

Answer (score 0):

I looked in more of your examples and I think my problem was simpler ( if there isn't any other solution) 
So what I did was I used **eval**:

button in view :

```
<input id="b_normal" type="button" value="normal" onClick="ajax('{{=URL('db_test')}}',[],':eval')" />
```

and the controller method:

> def db_test()
>
> ```
>  #tests and updates
>  return "jQuery('#b_normal').fadeOut();jQuery('#commDiv').show();"
> ```

for further refresh i used jquery, in view:

> jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
> var flag = '{{=flag_normal}}';
> if(flag == 'da')
>     jQuery('#b_normal').hide();
> else jQuery('#commDiv').hide();
> });
> ```

where *flag_normal* is sent by the main controller

I hope this is not too inefficient and if so, useful